# how to use web.reg_save_param when using javascript as scripting launguage in loadrunner?

Tags: javascript, loadrunner

I am trying to switch to javascript for scripting in loadrunner. While this process i recorded script by changing the script language and I got a script. Now when i was trying to correlate a parameter i am getting error as described below.

Loadrunner Version : 12.63

This code snippet is copied from MF documentation made made changes according to my need: [HERE](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/12.60-12.63/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param.htm%3FTocPath%3DWeb%2520Vuser%2520Functions%2520(WEB)%7CAlphabetical%2520List%2520of%2520Web%2520Vuser%2520Functions%7C_____39)

```
//  ClientID":"f3d65s4gs6dg4df65g465fd4","
    web.reg_save_param (""outFlightVal",
    new String []{
        "NOTFOUND=ERROR", 
        "LB=ClientID\":\"",
        "RB=\",\"" , 
        "LAST"} );
```

**ERROR :**

```
Action.js(142): Error: 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'.
    Source line: '  web.reg_save_param (""outFlightVal",'.
```

I even tried :

```
web.regSaveParamEx(paramName:"outFlightVal",lb:'ClientID":"',rb:'",');
```

**ERROR:**

```
Action.js(149): Error: 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'.
    Source line: '  web.regSaveParamEx(paramName:"outFlightVal",lb:'ClientID":"',rb:'",');'.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I got to know that the java code given in the documentation is not for javascript. it is for java Vuser which is used by some protocol like oracle DB, JMS ..etc

and web_reg_save_param is a older version of web_reg_save_param_ex and is no longer supported when we use javascript as a scripting language. so only web.regSaveParamEx is supported and it accepts an object so
**instead of :**

```
web.regSaveParamEx(paramName:"outFlightVal",lb:'ClientID":"',rb:'",');
```

**use :**

```
web.regSaveParamEx({paramName:"outFlightVal",lb:'ClientID":"',rb:'",'});
```